# Shuttle SZ77R5 USB Power before boot?

Tags: boot, bios, shuttle

Earlier this week I got a Shuttle SZ77R5 barebones kit, installed an i5 3750, 32gb ram, an ssd, and threw a fresh install of Ubuntu Quantal (12.10) on it.

This morning when I tried to get into the BIOS settings I noticed that the keyboard was unresponsive, and after hitting the 'f2' and 'del' keys the bios setup was just getting skipped and the machine was booting straight to ubuntu.

After playing around with it more I noticed that I couldn't get the caplock light to turn on for either my DAS Keyboard or Apple Wired usb keyboards -- until AFTER the OS had started booting. Which leads me to believe that there is some sort of 'fast boot' option turned on in the BIOS.

I looked through the manual for the motherboard and I didn't see anything other than "FastBoot: 'This item allows you to enable or disable Fast Boot function.'".

So I'm currently not able to get into the BIOS as the keyboard is not powered pre-boot - any ideas on how I would be able to reset this setting?

Any tips are much appreciated, thank you in advance.

NOTE: there are only usb ports for keyboards, no PS2 input :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem. Using the powered USB on the front panel worked for me.

Comment: So I ended up being able to do the same thing, but it was pretty wonky . The keyboard would work in the half second after I plugged it into one of the front usb ports. (but then immediately after stop working.